# Conjugate of eigen vector for complex matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove / Disprove ;

"If $z \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ is an eigenvector of $\Lambda \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ then $\bar{z}$ is also an eigenvector of $\Lambda$."

If $\Lambda$ is real, the statement is clear since complex Eigen values occured in conjugate pairs, but how to deal with complex matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any vector $z\in\mathbb C^2$ such that $z$ and $\overline{z}$ are linearly independent. Let $w$ be any vector that is linearly independent of $z$ (you may pick $w=\overline{z}$ if you want) and $\lambda$ be any complex number. Then $\Lambda=\pmatrix{z&w}\pmatrix{\lambda&1\\ 0&\lambda}\pmatrix{z&w}^{-1}$ is a matrix whose only eigenspace is $\operatorname{span}(z)\not\ni\overline{z}$. E.g. consider
$$
\Lambda=\pmatrix{1&0\\ i&1}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1&0\\ -i&1}
=\pmatrix{-i&1\\ 1&i}.
$$

Alternatively, pick any two vectors $z,w\in\mathbb C^2$ such that $z,\overline{z},w,\overline{w}$ are *pairwise* linearly independent (i.e. none of them is a scalar multiple of the other). Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be any two different complex numbers. Then $\Lambda=\pmatrix{z&w}\pmatrix{\lambda_1&0\\ 0&\lambda_2}\pmatrix{z&w}^{-1}$ is a matrix whose only eigenspaces $\operatorname{span}(z)$ and $\operatorname{span}(w)$ by design do not contain $\overline{z}$ or $\overline{w}$. E.g.
$$
\Lambda=\frac15\pmatrix{2&i\\ i&2}\pmatrix{5&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{2&-i\\ -i&2}
=\pmatrix{4&-2i\\ 2i&1}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the matrix $ \begin{pmatrix} 
1+i & 1-i \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $. It has a left eigenvector $(i,1)$ whose conjugate is not a left eigenvector of the matrix.